# sp_help with wildcards

Tags: sql-server

There is a command in SqlServer sp_help 'table_name' (table_name or other stuff)

Is there a possibility to use it when you don't know the whole table name, with wildcards or something like this:

> sp_help admin_**%**

EDIT:

Run `sp_help (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables  WHERE TABLE_NAME like '%admin_%')` but had a strange result...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `SP_HELP` requires a complete name, so use this to find the table name first:

```
SELECT
    *
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables
    WHERE TABLE_NAME like '%your table name guess here%'
```

then you can use `sp_help 'the_real_complete_name'`

**EDIT** based on OP's comment

You don't need to remember the query, just create a procedure to search for object names:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [FO] 
    @SearchFor sysname=''
AS

SELECT
    name,type_desc
    FROM sys.objects 
    WHERE name like '%'+@SearchFor+'%'
    ORDER BY type,name
GO
```

now just use it like:

```
fo 'xyz'
```

or

```
exec fo 'xyz'
```

to find all of the objects with a matching name.  These are the types of objects that can be found:

```
AGGREGATE_FUNCTION
CHECK_CONSTRAINT
DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT
FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT
PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT
SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE
CLR_STORED_PROCEDURE
SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION
CLR_SCALAR_FUNCTION
CLR_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION
RULE
REPLICATION_FILTER_PROCEDURE
SYNONYM
SERVICE_QUEUE
CLR_TRIGGER
SQL_TRIGGER
SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION
SQL_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION
USER_TABLE
UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT
VIEW
EXTENDED_STORED_PROCEDURE
INTERNAL_TABLE
```

This is off the main topic, but you can also search for any text within a stored procedure, trigger, view, or function using this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [FT]
    @Search varchar(255)
AS

SELECT DISTINCT
    o.name,o.type_desc
    FROM sys.sql_modules        m
        INNER JOIN sys.objects  o ON m.object_id=o.object_id
    WHERE m.definition Like '%'+@Search+'%'
    ORDER BY type_desc

GO
```

just use it like:

```
ft 'fkgjfg'
```

or

```
exec ft 'fkgjfg'
```

Comment: yeah. this helps, a little long and should remember.

Answer (score 1):

The following query will give you a list of tables that match the name you want.

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables 
where TABLE_NAME like 'admin%'
```

You can then execute `sp_help` on the resulting table name.

Answer (score 0):

It [doesn't look like it's meant to be used this way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187335%28SQL.90%29.aspx). I bet someone here will come up with another way around it though!

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to implement something special with the functionality of sp_help you can create your own version by copying its source. (`sp_helptext sp_help`)